# Wordpress - how to add general content area to a specific “page” that's not actually a page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I purchased a WP theme https://themeforest.net/item/pressville-municipal-wordpress-theme/19949423 and need to add general content area to the People page: https://preview.themeforest.net/item/pressville-municipal-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/19949423?_ga=2.67243158.624148492.1570058772-1881232054.1569979687

The People page is actually a section in the WP dashboard (kind of like Media or Portfolio section) so technically not a editable page in the WP backend. I contacted the theme creator and was told that it's customization (not included w/theme) and advised to hard code text into the php. The problem with that is it's not accessible to other users who have no design or code background.. Is there a way to create a page with editable content block for this People section so it's easily editable without knowing code?

[image]
[image]

Also, the “People” header text changes if you click on subcategories (to “Elected Officials”) for example. When you click a subcategory, the main menu (People page) no longer shows as active which can be confusing to users. Is there a way to fix this so header stays consistent (like Contact page header) and menu item shows active regardless of what subcategory(All, Elected Officials, etc) is selected on the People page? Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a regular page called "People's page" and add text to it. Then if you want to show that page's content into a PHP template you can do the following:

**Step 1. Create the Function**

Open up your theme’s functions.php file and paste the following code, likely at the bottom of the page.

```
function cn_include_content($pid) {
    $thepageinquestion = get_post($pid);
    $content = $thepageinquestion->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    echo $content;
}
```

**Step 2. Use the Function in a Template File**

Next, open up the specific template file you want to include the Page’s content on and paste in the function:

```
<?php cn_include_content(31); ?>
```

Replace `31` with the ID of the Page you want to include. [How to find a page ID](https://www.competethemes.com/blog/find-page-id/).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking to do! Is there a way to keep main nav menu item "People" to show as actively selected regardless of the filter toggling? I was told by theme developer it's not as simple as it seems and can not be done due to limitations of WP setup..

Comment: That would be another set of problems too extensive for this support request. Try opening a new request and explain the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is sounds like you need to go to your wp-admin and click appearance/ menus. Here you can remove these menu items that might be default but have no pages associated with them. You can then add the pages you want and come back and create a custom menu. Hope that answers the first part of your question.

Comment: Thanks, I cleared the menu with any unused pages but People is technically not a page but a section of the theme like Media..MistaPrime suggestion seems to work so now trying to figure out menu/page title..

Comment: Wow that is really strange, I would push the developer a little more because it seems very no-user friendly to sell a template that can not be edited easily.

Comment: I was told it's not as simple as it seems to keep the People nav item active when toggling from All to other filter opts. That it's a limitation of what can be done on WP...